# UDP server send/receive

Tags: java, netty, reactor

I need to send a request and then get a response. How to do it in reactor netty?

```
 UdpServer.create()
                        .host("127.0.0.1")
                        .port(55953)
                        .handle((UdpInbound udpInbound, UdpOutbound udpOutbound) ->
                           udpOutbound.sendString(Mono.just("hello")).then(
                                    udpInbound.receive().asByteArray().then().log("info"))
                        )
                .bindNow(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
```

Comment: This has all of the information you need here; https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/master/src/docs/asciidoc/udp-server.adoc

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the answer, I watched it but unfortunately did not find what I need.